# Displaying data from Firebase in React without arrays

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to both React and Firebase. I struggled a bit to get data from the database, even though the instructions on the Firebase website were pretty straightforward.

I managed to print data in the view by using this code:

**Get data from DB and save it in state:**

```
INSTRUMENTS_DB.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        this.state.instruments.push(snapshot.val());
        this.setState({
            instruments: this.state.instruments
        });
```

**From Firebase, I receive and Object containing several objects, which correspond to the differen instruments, like shown in the following snippet:**

```
Object {
    Object {
        name: "Electric guitar",
        image: "img/guitar.svg"
    }
    Object {
        name: "Bass guitar",
        image: "img/bass.svg"
    }
    // and so on..
}
```

**Currently, I print data by populating an array like this:**

```
var rows = [];
    for (var obj in this.state.instruments[0]) {
        rows.push(<Instrument name={this.state.instruments[0][obj].name}
                              image={this.state.instruments[0][obj].image}/>);
    }
```

I feel like there's a better way to do it, can somedody give a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `map` function only works for arrays, so using directly it on this object won't work.

#### What you can do instead is:

Call the `map` function **on the keys** of your object using `Object.keys()`:

```
getInstrumentRows() {
  const instruments = this.state.instruments;
  Object.keys(instruments).map((key, index) => {
    let instrument = instruments[key];
    // You can now use instrument.name and instrument.image
    return  <Instrument name={instrument.name} image={instrument.image}/>
  });
}
```

*Alternatively*, you can also import the [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) library and use its [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#map) method which would allow you to refactor the above code into:

```
getInstrumentRowsUsingLodash() {
  const instruments = this.state.instruments;
    _.map(instruments, (key, index) => {
    let instrument = instruments[key];
    // You can now use instrument.name and instrument.image
    return  <Instrument name={instrument.name} image={instrument.image}/>
  });
}
```

---

*Side note:
When you retrieve you data from Firebase you attempt to update the state directly with a call on `this.state.instruments`.  The `state` in React should be treated as Immutable and should not be mutated with direct calls to it like push.*

Comment: Thanks! I used the first solution and I could finally access the instrument properties!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

I user firebase a lot and mu solution is little **ES6** helper function

> const toArray = function (firebaseObj) {
>
> ```
> return Object.keys(firebaseObj).map((key)=> {
>     return Object.assign(firebaseObj[key], {key});
> })
> ```
>
> };

I also assign the firebase key to object key property, so later I can work with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would use map function:

```
_getInstrumentRows() {
    const instruments = this.state.instruments[0];
    if (instruments) {
        return instruments.map((instrument) => 
            <Instrument name={instrument.name}
                        image={instrument.image}/>);
    }
}
```

In your `render()` method you just use `{_getInstrumentRows()}`  wherever you need it.